# Generic way to create table using google docs api in python

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I'm sorry that I'm asking too many Google docs related questions but I'm trying to make my document creation more generic and it seems very complex
Here, I'm trying to create dynamic table using google docs API but there are some issues which I'm unable to resolve.

```
def create_table(row, column, table_index):
    table_body = {
        "insertTable":
            {
                "rows": row,
                "columns": column,
                "location":
                    {
                        "index": table_index
                    }
            }
    }
    return table_body


def insert_table_data(row, column, text):
    table_data = []
    index = 0
    for i in range(row):
        inp_text = text[i]
        for j in range(column):
            index += 5
            insert_value = {
                "insertText":
                    {
                        "text": inp_text[j],
                        "location":
                            {
                                "index": index
                            }
                    }

            }
            table_data.append(insert_value)
        index = 0
    print(table_data)
    return table_data

request = []
file_id = ######
requests.append(create_table(2, 2, 1))
text = [['Name', 'XYZ'], ['Industry', 'Software']]
requests.append(insert_table_data(2, 2, text))
docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

Here, I'm trying to create 2*2 table and insert the `text` data. For cell indexing, I followed the following approach (I took it from Tanaike's answer)

- For the row, the index is required to set every 5 index.
- For the column, the index is required to set every 2 index.

I'm unable to change the index when row is changing. I'm getting the following payload for the table content.

```
[
   {
      "insertText":{
         "text":"Name",
         "location":{
            "index":5
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "insertText":{
         "text":"XYZ",
         "location":{
            "index":10
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "insertText":{
         "text":"Industry",
         "location":{
            "index":5
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "insertText":{
         "text":"Software",
         "location":{
            "index":10
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Expected Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Tanaike's tutorial](https://tanaikech.github.io/2019/05/22/creating-new-table-and-putting-values-to-cells-using-google-docs-api-with-google-apps-script/),

> For the row, the index is required to set every 5 index. For the
> column, the index is required to set every 2 index.

Note:

- You need to insert your text request on descending order (last row and last column first, followed by last row, first column and so on...). This should be arrange that way so that your index will not adjust as you add text in your table.

### Sample Code:

```
def insert_table_data(row, column, text):
    table_data = []
    index = 0
    for i in reversed(range(row)):
        inp_text = text[i]
        rowIndex = (i+1)*5
        for j in reversed(range(column)):
            index = rowIndex + (j*2)
            insert_value = {
                "insertText":
                    {
                        "text": inp_text[j],
                        "location":
                            {
                                "index": index
                            }
                    }

            }
            table_data.append(insert_value)

    print(table_data)
    return table_data
```

### What it does?

- Reverse the loop of the row index. Row index should be divisible by 5 (add 1 offset in the row index since arrays are zero-indexed)
- Reverse loop the column index (+2 offset should be added in the row index depending on your column count)

### Sample Request:

```
{
   "insertText":{
      "text":"Software",
      "location":{
         "index":12
      }
   }
},
{
   "insertText":{
      "text":"Industry",
      "location":{
         "index":10
      }
   }
},
{
   "insertText":{
      "text":"XYZ",
      "location":{
         "index":7
      }
   }
},
{
   "insertText":{
      "text":"Name",
      "location":{
         "index":5
      }
   }
}
```

### Sample Output

[image]